# What are the most recommended non-biased books on Egyptian History

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-egypt, egypt, hieroglyphs

I am new to Egyptology, what are the most recommended non-biased books on Egyptian History, Hieroglyphs, mythology, etc... that are not biased and written by experts in the field?

By non biased, I mean that they were not written by people who tend to brighten (or the opposite) the Egyptian history (for example if they are Egyptians).

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. Source requests are generally off-topic on this site. You might find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [What topics can I ask about here?](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [ask].

Comment: I would assume that most Egyptian history books written by Egyptians are as biased as American  history books written by Americans or French history books written by the French.  Bias is a part of human nature.

Comment: Even AI will be as biased as the information it was trained on.  https://www.forbes.com/sites/tomtaulli/2019/08/04/bias-the-silent-killer-of-ai-artificial-intelligence/#702f98727d87

Comment: @ed.hank -I don't know that there's a formal name for this, but as a holder of a CS masters who has studied AI, personally I prefer to call this phenomenon **[RIRO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)** (Racist In, Racist Out).

Comment: @T.E.D. I like that term,  dont mind me if i borrow it in the future!

Comment: @T.E.D. As another holder of a CS Masters who has studied & developed AI & Machine Learning systems, I can confirm that I have seen that exact term used, for example in the context of [Micro$oft's Tay Twitter-bot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tay_(bot)).

Comment: Herodotus history of Egypt was great.  Of course it has a bias of his being greek.  And It's also biased by his wanting to tell a good story.  As I recall he did actually travel to Egypt and was pretty good at pointing out things he saw himself and things he was told by others.  It is really the first "history" as such that we have today.

Comment: @Danny: Don't you think that Herodotus book is a bit out of date? That we know very much more about Egypt than Herodotus? (He even could not read hieroglyphs!)

Comment: @Alex of course Herodotus wrote his histories some 2,400 years ago.  But that's what makes it so cool.   Sure now we can read hieroglyphs (which is amazing), but Herodotus actually talked to the priests of ancient Egypt , and wrote down what they said!  It's totally worth reading, along with more modern works.

Comment: You may be assuming more connection between ancient and modern-day Egypt.  It's an entirely different culture, speaking a different language, mostly practicing a different religion, and with probably not even a whole lot of common ancestry.  It would be like trying to relate the builders of Stonehenge to modern-day English people.

Comment: @sempaiscuba - Its quite possible I heard the term in a media report about Tay, but its a good way of thinking about the problem that needs to be employed more than it is. I think there was another example this week where Apple's credit algorithm was consistently giving women in community property states with better credit ratings than their husbands *lower* credit limits.

Answer (score 3):

## There are no *non-biased* histories.

Histories are always written by people, and these people have viewpoints. They list just the facts about kings and battles, ignoring the common people? *That's a bias.* They focus on the patterns of social development, ignoring the kings and battles? *That's a bias.*

Historians learn to question their [primary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_source) and [secondary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_source) sources. Who wrote it? Who was the audience? What was the motive for writing? No different with [tertiary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tertiary_source) sources. Read several histories, compare them, think about the authors.

At most, you will find one whose biases agree with your own and believe that it is bias-free. But it isn't. That is called an [echo chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_chamber_(media)) effect.

Answer (score 2):

You may begin with: 
Redford, Donald B., ed. (2001). The Oxford Encyclopedia of Ancient Egypt.
for a general account. Ancient Egypt existed for very long time, and it has been very much
studied, with plenty of books written on specific periods and various aspects of its history. This one can give you a general orientation.

You do not have to worry that books on ancient Egypt may be biased: the modern Egyptians (Arabs) have nothing to do with ancient Egypt. Even not related:-)
Ancient Egypt was first conquered by Persians (26 centuries ago), then by Macedonians, then by the Roman empire, and finally by the Arabs. So its culture (including the language, writing, religion, etc.) was completely forgotten in the process, and was only recovered by the modern science, after their ancient writing was deciphered in the early 19th century.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the assertion that bias is not a concern wrt ancient Egypt. You may already be aware of the [Black Egyptian hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Egyptian_hypothesis) which easily connects to all kinds of debates about racism. Further, the amount of fringe-history bullshit you can find on the pyramids, the Sphinx, and the [Dendera light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendera_light) is absolutely breathtaking. These are only two examples; there is obviously much, much more.

Comment: @0range: I did not mean bullshit history, but only the professional, mainstream one. This kind of fringe history can be found on any country.